# How to fetch views field label in hook_views_pre_render?

Tags: views

[image]

How to fetch views field label to modify in hook_views_pre_render ?

```
  function mymodule_views_pre_render(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if($view->id() == 'mytype'){
    // Here I want to fetch the field label but I am not getting how to fetch field label
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$view->field[{field machine name}]->options['label']`

The `$view` object has a property 'field', which is an array of all fields set in your view. You need to select the one labeled 'Name'.

Each field is listed using its machine name as key, hence `{field machine name}` as a placeholder. You need to replace that with the actual machine name.

The field in that list again is an object, with a property 'options'. This is an array of all options, including alterations, whether the field is excluded or not, etc. In those options is also an index called 'label', which contains the field's label.